# Saving card details to customer using Stripe Elements

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a little store I'm setting up, and so far, it's relatively simple. You can either order the product one time, weekly, or monthly.

I have set up the corresponding products in the Stripe Dashboard.

If the client sends that they want a recurring order, it creates a `Customer` with their information.

But whenever I try and create a recurring order, I receive a `This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method. thrown in`.

I'm using Stripe Elements, and since the card data never goes to my server, I'm not sure how to go about adding a payment method to this `Customer`.

Create subscription:

```php
\Stripe\Subscription::create([
       'customer' => $customer_id,
       'items' => [
       [
            'price' => 'price_id_2',
            'quantity' => $qty_1,
            'price' => 'price_id_2',
            'quantity' => $qty_2,
        ],
    ],
]);
```

`$.post` to send data to the PHP file

```js
$.post('./secret.php', data, null, "json")
    .done(function(data) {
        clientSecret = data.client_secret;

        stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: card,
            }
        }).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
                console.log(result.error.message);
            } else {
                if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                    console.log("Payment success.");
                    document.getElementById("processing").classList.add("hide");
                    document.getElementById("order-success").classList.remove("hide");
                }
            }
        })
    })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        document.getElementById("processing").classList.add("hide");
        document.getElementById("order-failure").classList.remove("hide");
    });
```

My one-time order works fine, but I just can't understand how to do this. The Docs show "Saving Card Data" as a deprecated utility, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you likely want to save a card during the payment process: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

Comment: I think you're right, no idea why it didn't show up when I was searching for it!

Comment: It seems like you have to create an initial payment, and then create a subscription after that? I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: You can also just save it without the payment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse